# How to model recursive data in firestore?

Tags: model, google-cloud-firestore, recursive-datastructures

I have this data

```
id: aBc123
author: "commentator1"
content : "this is a comment"
date: "today"
email: "commentator1@domain.com"
replies:
    id: Xuz231
    author: "replier1"
    content : "this is a reply"
    date: "today"
    email: "replier1@domain.com"
    replies:
        id: X1u2v3
        author: "replier11"
        content : "this is a reply"
        date: "now"
        email: "replier11@domain.com"
        replies:
            (etc)
            (etc)
```

I want to model this in firestore database and be able to save and retrieve data from this model. How do i do that ?

Comment: That's the schema for a document, right? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes that's the schema. I would like to represent it like a recursive data structure but don't even where to start. What I've tried so is just the data structure without the recursive part which is straightforward but now I want to extend it to have a recursive structure but don't know where to start.

Comment: Try to create a class that matches that structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo there is no class creation in firestore ?

Comment: A class that will help you map those properties, right?